# Send files to PHP application using ASP.NET (vb)

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net, dotnetnuke

Currently I am working in the integration of OSTicket to provide a better way to support customers.

My client has a `DotNetNuke` site and I have to integrate a form with `OSTicket`.

DotNetNuke and OSTicket are hosted in different sites and have different domains.

So far, I'm able to create a new ticket using the system (not directly sending data to MySql) but now i need to send attachments with the tickets

My main question is how to send a file using post with asp.net to php and how handle the sent file with php

EDIT: 
I can't create a form and point it to the php file:

a) For some reasong, all forms i create on WebUserControls for DNN dissapear
b) The User never has to leave the site

Answer (score 1):

The reason the form disappears is that DNN has a surrounding form (and you can't have a form within a form).

If you really need to post this way, use an iframe in DotNetNuke to a standalone asp.net page which will allow you to use the solution above. Otherwise, I would look to see if there is better API integration.

Answer (score 0):

Just Output the form in ASP.NET, with action="yourfile.php" and enctype="multipart/form-data". In PHP you can now use the $_FILES global var to access the posted file

```php
<form action="yourfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For php see: http://php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.post-method.php